# AFJSONRequestOperation hitting failed block on 200 response.statusCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afjsonrequestoperation

My AFJSONRequestOperation is hitting the failure block on a 200 response. Is this because I have additional JSON?

```
 [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *d = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    bool required = [d[@"payment_required"] boolValue];
    [self.delegate paymentRequired:required];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    int statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;
    NSLog(@"status code: %d response: %@", statusCode, operation.responseString);
    if (operation.response.statusCode == 402) {
        [self.delegate paymentRequired:true];
        return ;
    }
    [self handleOperationFailed:operation action:^{
        [self determinePaymentRequired];
    }];
}];
```

yields in console

```
status code: 200 response: {'payment_required':'false'}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. It has single quotes (`{'payment_required':'false'}`), but JSON format needs them to be double ones:

```
{
     "payment_required" : false 
}
```

PS: I also removed quotes on `false`, because `false` is a valid value (and it's preferred).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, there are 3 condition you need to meet to hit the success block:

1. **200** response code
2. a proper **JSON object** included in the response
3. the Content-Type of the response is set to **application/json**

Hope this can help you.